# Determine TLS versions supported by curl

Tags: shell-script, curl

How can I check from a Bash script if the `curl` executable in PATH supports `tlsv1.0` or `tlsv1.1` or newer?

Basically I would like to inform the user if its `curl` does not support TLS v1.2 and take the necessary actions. I will run the script in an **embedded system** that has Busybox and a custom Linux environment (a NAS, specifically) so I cannot rely in a Linux distribution.

Below there are two examples (*system1* and *system2*); I could `grep` for the command-line switches, but is this a good practice?

```bsh
[system1:~] # curl --version
curl 7.21.0 (i686-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.21.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8e zlib/1.2.3.3 libidn/1.0
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM SSL libz

[system1:~] # curl --help all | grep -- --tlsv
 -1/--tlsv1         Use TLSv1 (SSL)


[system2:~] # curl --version
curl 7.76.0 (x86_64-openwrt-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.76.0 OpenSSL/1.1.1h zlib/1.2.11
Release-Date: 2021-03-31
Protocols: file ftp ftps http https imap imaps mqtt pop3 pop3s rtsp smtp smtps tftp
Features: alt-svc HTTPS-proxy IPv6 Largefile libz SSL

[system2:~] # curl --help all | grep -- --tlsv
 -1, --tlsv1         Use TLSv1.0 or greater
     --tlsv1.0       Use TLSv1.0 or greater
     --tlsv1.1       Use TLSv1.1 or greater
     --tlsv1.2       Use TLSv1.2 or greater
     --tlsv1.3       Use TLSv1.3 or greater
```

Comment: I'am agree with you. Make a `grep` on help message is never a good solution. I have posted another solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```bsh
curl --tlsv1.2 --silent --connect-timeout 1 --url 'http://localhost:1' 2>/dev/null
if [[ $? -eq 2 ]]; then # 2 == CURLE_FAILED_INIT
    echo "TLS 1.2 protocol not supported by this cURL version"
fi
```

Comment: Sounds good! But this way I should hardcode `--tlsv1.2`... is there anything else that lists the supported encryption protocols, excluding the help messages?